# Is explorer.exe always in the "C:\Windows\" folder?

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, windows-server

I'm writing a program that needs to find `explorer.exe`, but I don't know if it's always in the same folder or not.

I know on all modern versions of Windows you can find `explorer.exe` in the `C:\Windows\` directory, but is this always the case for every version of Windows Desktop and Windows Server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Explorer.exe is located at

> %windir%\explorer.exe

On 64 bit systems there is also a 32 bit version located in

> %windir%\SysWOW64\explorer.exe

on emulators or other types of 32bit systems.

You also will need to consider CLI based server environments where the GUI module hasn't been installed so the file wouldn't exist but I'm assuming if you're searching for explorer.exe, it is GUI related, so might be irrelevant in this case.

Comment: What about versions older than Windows 95 (not 64bit or 32bit)? Are they also still in the same directory?

Comment: I think they were 16bit versions but Windows 3.1 is the only one preceeding Win95 with a GUI in 16bit. Win3.1 explorer name was "Winfile.exe" and was also stored inside the windows directory. I'm curious to know what you're working on now. Haha

Comment: @ShaunRoselt I don't want to come across too hostile, but… is that really relevant? If you're trying to create software for Windows 95, surely you have a test environment where you could check this. Also, Windows 95 is a 32-bit operating system.

Comment: I meant Windows 3.1 was 16bit.